# I want to use constraints 'InList' to validate domain ,how to ignore senstive(Case-insensitive)

Tags: validation, grails

code:`static constraints = {
        titleStr size:1..120
        categoryStr nullable: false,inList:['For Sale', 'For Rent']
}`
when categoryStr is For rent ,it will return error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a [custom validator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) to do the case insensitive check:

```
static constraints = {
    titleStr size:1..120
    categoryStr validator: { ['for sale', 'for rent'].contains(it.toLowerCase()) }
}
```

Comment: messages are defined in `messages.properties`.  Check the [docs](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) for how to configure the messages.